# Unable to find value by key in dictionary in case of comma separated key

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary like below where i store list of file names with key generated as Csv1,Csv2 based on number of files.

I have a string array like below :

```
string[] files = { "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv"};
 int counter=1;
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 foreach (var file in files)
 {
     dictionary.Add("CSV" + counter, file);
     counter++;
 }

 foreach (var file in files)
 {
       string myValue;
       if (dictionary.TryGetValue(file, out myValue))    // getting null in out value
 }
```

When i try to search for **SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv** i am getting null in my **myValue variable.**

**Screenshot**:[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update**:i realize that i was adding wrong key so changed it like below but still unable to find CSV1 in case of SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv:

```
foreach (var file in files)
 {
     dictionary.Add(file,"CSV" + counter);
     counter++;
 }
```

Comment: You need to iterate over your dictionary manually if you want to find entires by value

Comment: are them "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv" together or should be separated ?

Comment: @hasnayn:They should be together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment you said in Amir Popoviches answer. I think you should alter your dictionary construction.

So you will create a mapping from each of the .csv file(s) to the "CSV1" etc string.

```
var files = new[] { "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv" };
var counter = 1;
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach (var item in file.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        dictionary.Add(item, "CSV" + counter);
    }

    counter++;
}
```

And as you said in comments you want to find what "CSVX" file is for each of the files you have so we simulate you trying to find a match for these files. Notice that this array has all separate file names, in the upper array we had values comma separated so we group them together.

```
var files2 = new[] { "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv" };
foreach (var file in files2)
{
    string csvValue;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(file, out csvValue))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", file, csvValue);
    }
}
```

This should output you

```
SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv -> CSV1
SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv -> CSV1
SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv -> CSV2
```

Comment: Sorry i have a question that TryGetValue function matches exact value or it is like contains function??

Comment: It will search the dictionary for the value with the key and return true/false depending whether the value was found or not and the out parameter is populated by the value, so it can be used in the calling code. So it is more than contains function.

Comment: Too late to edit. It is does more than the ContainsKey function. However it will not do a contains search within the key, you would have to do it manually, if you want partial matches.

Comment: Yes this worked.thank you so much for the kind help and please keep helping like this.Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

First argument in TryGetValue is key. So you should pass there "CSV" + counter to make it works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are adding items to the dictionary with the following keys:

`"CSV" + counter -> CSV1, CSV2...`

And you are trying to find different values (e.g. `"SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv"`) here:

```
foreach (var file in files)
 {
       string myValue;
       if (dictionary.TryGetValue(file, out myValue))    // getting null in out value
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to find SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv value and based on that i want to get CSV1 etc..

Comment: So you need to insert the items this way:
`dictionary.Add(file, "CSV" + counter);`

Comment: yeah i changes it but still i am unable to find SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv in case of first record value i.e SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv

Comment: Change your array from `{ "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv"}` to `{ "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv"}`

Comment: But i want to keep CSV1 common for both this file name :SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv so when any one of this file name comes i want to get CSV1

Comment: Then in your first foreach, split the value by , and add.

 `foreach (var file in files)
 {
     foreach(var splitted in file.Split(','))
     {
      dictionary.Add(splitted, "CSV" + counter);
     }
     counter++;
 }`

Comment: @Learning - Does this solution suit you?

Comment: Sorry but this foreach (var file in files) { foreach(var splitted in file.Split(',')) { dictionary.Add(splitted, "CSV" + counter); } counter++; } will produce 2 CSV for SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv and i want only 1 CSV to be share between this 2 :SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv

Comment: No it wont. The counter increments only after you handle the splitted values.

Comment: @Learning - BTW, you can create a "one liner":
`var dictionary = files.Select((k, i) => new { Index = i + 1, Keys = k.Split(',') }).SelectMany(i => i.Keys.Select(k => new { Index = i.Index, Key = k})).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => "CSV" + i.Index);`

Answer (score 1):

Try below updated code:

```
        string[] files = { "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv,SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv", "SampleCSVFile_5300kb3.csv" };
        int counter = 1;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            dictionary.Add("CSV" + counter, file);
            counter++;
        }

        counter = 1;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           string myValue;

           //You need to pass key name here  but you are passing value of it
           //Need to update here 
           string keyName = "CSV" + counter;
           if (dictionary.TryGetValue(keyName, out myValue)) ;    // getting null in out value
            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the dictionary an find your desired value using split by comma. you will get "SampleCSVFile_5300kb1.csv" and "SampleCSVFile_5300kb2.csv" into the `fileName` array for the same `myvalKey`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
        {
            string myvalKey = entry.Key;
            string myval = entry.Value;

            if (myval.Contains(',')) {
                string[] fileNames = myval.Split(',');

            }                                
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you seem to be looking for a way to match only part of a key. And while I suggest using the answers of [Janne Matikainen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680337/janne-matikainen) and just add the parts of your key separately with the same value, regardless I will give you a way to match on a partial key using a bit of Linq.

```
string resultValue = null;
string resultKey = dictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Contains(file));
if(resultKey != null)
  resultValue = dictionary[resultKey];
```

this does assume only the first match is wanted, if you want all matching keys replace FirstOrDefault with Where.

Beware that while this code is easy it is not suitable for when performance is critical as you iterate over the keys basically using the dictionary as a

```
List<Tuple<string,string>>
```